# Microsoft Access Sequential Concatenated keys

Tags: ms-access, composite-primary-key

My employer has multiple sites (300+) and wants to track jobs reqs by the siteID and a sequential jobID.  I'd like to have a concatenated key of a the siteID followed by a sequential jobID, so that each site's jobID is sequential to the particular site.  Is there a way to arrange for an autonumbering key like that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a composite key. The first field being the site identifier and the second being the identity field.

Comment: That's my intention.  Sorry if concatenated isn't synonymous with composite.  The problem is the sequential part.  If site 1 is on req 5, the employer wants its next jobID to be six while site 2 might be on jobID 9.  Am I making sense yet?

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Since you are using Access, you are pretty limited in what you can do. If this was SQL Server, I could recommend a trigger that would do what you want. The only thing I could suggest would be possibly Data Macros (Access 2010+). You might be able to use the AferInsert event to populate a field with the ID you need. I haven't really used them much, but you might find some valuable information here: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx